# redux-form, submit form with an error

Tags: redux-form

I have a form, and on one field I want to show a validation error (as an information for a user) but I don't want this error to prevent submitting the form.

I would appreciate any hint, how to do this...

---EDIT---

I was asked to provide an example. Please use as an example this provided by redux-form: http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/

```
<Field name="username" type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    validate={[ required, maxLength15 ]}
/>
```

Here are 2 validate functions: `required` and `maxLength15`. I would like to allow user submit the form even if the `maxLength15` returns the error message. I want to show the message but allow the form submit

Comment: please provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to submit, then you should use warnings instead of error. redux-form won't let you submit it otherwise.

To do this using field-level validations, you can simply change the `validate` prop with the `warn` prop:

```
<Field name="username" type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    warn={[ required, maxLength15 ]}
/>
```

Comment: It works almost as I needed. just the warning appears by default, is there any way to show in the moment of field edition or in the moment when submit button is clicked?